# When to use `StreamBlock` vs `StructBlock`?

Tags: wagtail

In Wagtail, [StreamBlock](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html#streamblock) and [StructBlock](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html#structblock) seem to serve the same purpose, which is to nest other child blocks in a parent field.

When to use one versus the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use StructBlock if you have a known, well-defined set of sub-elements to include in a block.

Use StreamBlock when you want an variable number of content items of mixed types.

Comment: Got it, `StreamBlock` is simlar to `StructBlock`, except it allows you to repeat and rearrange child blocks, which is not the case with `StructBlock`.